# I have to loop through an Images folder and encode each image. But I can't encode whenever I add new images and am getting an error

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

so here I have to loop through the file Images and encode each image and save the encodings in a list. but I am getting a Index error. Just to pinpoint you can check the findencodings function where encoding is done. And the imgList where we are storing the path names of list.

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import pickle
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import storage

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
    credentials
})

# Importing the student images
folderPath = 'Images'
pathList = os.listdir(folderPath)
print(pathList)
imgList = []
studentIds = []
for path in pathList:
    imgList.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(folderPath,path)))
    studentIds.append(os.path.splitext(path)[0])


    fileName = f'{folderPath}/{path}'
    bucket = storage.bucket()
    blob = bucket.blob(fileName)
    blob.upload_from_filename(fileName)



    #print(os.path.splitext(path)[0])
print(studentIds)

def findEncodings(imagesList):
    encodeList = []
    for img in imagesList:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList
print("encoding started...")
encodeListKnown = findEncodings(imgList)
encodingListKnowWithIds = [encodeListKnown, studentIds]
print("encoding complete")

file = open("EncodeFile.p",'wb')
pickle.dump(encodingListKnowWithIds, file)
file.close()
print("File Saved")
```

The error is

```
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Major1\EncodeGenerator.py", line 45, in <module>
    encodeListKnown = findEncodings(imgList)
  File "D:\Major1\EncodeGenerator.py", line 41, in findEncodings
    encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can't really understand how to solve error, i thought the index would increase dynamically.